# Taking individual lists from a vertical array and storing them horizontally

Tags: java, arrays, string, matrix, weka

I have a one-dimensional String so `n x 1` where each string is a unique array in that one column per row, given as an ArrayList:

```
[x]
[y]
[z]
```

However, I would like to know how to do this in a general sense where the number of arrays or list aren't known. Hence, something like `list.all(valueHere)` has to be implemented.

Expected output - Something like:

```
[x][y][z]
```

edited:
Essentially, perhaps a for-loop that can do this:
Where the individual lists are selected from within a loop, perhaps by their length, then pasted beside one another or stored as a list horizontally.

Perhaps an empty array is needed, which uses those to fill them in:

```
//step 1
[x]
[y]
[z]

//step2
[x][y]
[z]

//step3
[x][y][z]

//second example

/empty array
[][][]
//list
[x]
[y]
[z]

//step 1

[x][][]

[y]
[z]

//step 2
[x][y][]

[z]

//step 3
[x][y][z]
```

I have managed to get the first element on this list by doing, though not all of it will be replaced:

```java
String[] yourArr = new String[test.numInstances()];

for(int i = 0; i<test.numInstances();i++) {
    String  trueClassLabel = test.instance(i).toString(test.classIndex());
    s = new String[] {trueClassLabel};
    yourArr[i] = s[i];
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(yourArr));
}
```

output:

> [Loss, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]

Comment: You could join the string array like this: String.join(" ", t). Reverse operation would be split(" ")

Comment: add your current output and expected output

Comment: @Stackbeans in a sence, this one dimensional array is a horizontal one. It depends how you interpret your code and your datastructure.

Comment: There is no flipping in a one dim array?

Comment: Why not turn the 1dim array of strings into a real 2-dim array of char, and transpose that? A 1dim thing has only 1 dimension. If you consider the chars in your strings as rows, then well, turn it into a real matrix of columns and rows.

Comment: @GhostCat I have updated this question instead of proposing a new one. This is what I was originally after. Perhaps the 'Duplicated questions', do not apply anymore?

Comment: I am still not exactly clear what you want. In your last example, the 1-dim list ... is the input, and that triangle of lists is the expected output you want?

Comment: @GhostCat The last row of the triangle list is what I'm after. I thought of implementing it into a list, then selecting the last list as it is in a horizontal format. Though, the code I use grabs it in a vertical form.

Comment: The last line of the triangle is exactly your input, just printed differently? I dont see any transposing here. You have an array 1 2 3, and the only difference is whether you print them with spaces or new lines between the values?

Comment: @GhostCat I'll have to try out your perspective - How would I approach the input data by removing the new lines? They're instances data from a `.arff` file.

Comment: Now you are again asking about something else. I dont know what arff files are, I dont know how the data looks like. All I can tell you, as I did hours before: the examples you are showing are really nothing else but "how do I print the words in a string array"

Comment: @GhostCat I had another interpretation towards this, and that's by storing each individual value into a separate array within a loop. For example, the first row `Loss` is stored as a list into a separate array, then the second row `Loss` stored as the next array besides the first etc ... I'll try working on this though some insight on this approach is much appreciated! Thank you so much for your effort and time GhostCat, you're the best! I'll update the question as you're right, a new approach is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of reading and utilising the insight provided by @GhostCat I have managed to figure out what I need.

I first had to create a dummy array that was empty:

```
String[] submit = null;
```

Along with another dummy array that contains the length of the number of instances (or the length of String I'm after)

```
String[] yourArr = new String[test.numInstances()];
```

Then create a for loop that stores the instances from the class index for the `.arff` data into an array. Then store that array into the ampty array `yourArr`, and finally copy this range into a different one:

```
for(int i = 0; i<test.numInstances();i++) {
String  trueClassLabel = test.instance(i).toString(test.classIndex());
s = new String[] {trueClassLabel};
yourArr[i] = s[0];
submit = Arrays.copyOfRange(yourArr, 0, i);
}
```

Then print the string as an array outside the loop:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(submit));
```

Output:

> [Loss, Loss, Loss, Draw, Win, Loss, Loss, Draw, Win, Win, Win, Win]